How to read request body and query params in next 13's API with app router in route.tsfile?
I created an API route in Next.js 13 using the new app router. The route handles both GET and POST requests, demonstrating how to read query parameters and request bodies. This approach allows you to build robust and flexible API endpoints in your Next.js application.
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);

  const queryParam = searchParams.get("param") || "default";

  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Query param value is ${queryParam}" });
}

I did not find any solution here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route

You are missing NextRequest:

NextRequest extends the Web Request API with additional convenience methods.

NextRequest has a property called nextUrl:

nextUrl
Extends the native URL API with additional convenience methods, including Next.js specific properties.

Now nextUrl has searchParams which you can use to retrive the query parameters.
// import NextRequest
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const queryParam = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("param") || "default";

  // use backticks instead of double qoutes to have access to queryParam
  return NextResponse.json({ message: `Query param value is ${queryParam}` });
}

